# How to create a massive or group sms message in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sms

Using `broadbandStick` to create a massage and working in c# windows.

How to create a massive sms message or group message using my database SQL?

Here is my Table

```
-------------------------------
|ConactNo |Grades|Average|Remarks|
|-------- |------|-------|-------|
|//DigitNo|    80|   82.5|PASSED |
|//DigitNo|    86|     81|PASSED |
|//DigitNo|    72|   73.5|FAILED |
---------------------------------
```

I have a 11 digit number in `ContactNo` Column, If clicked on `SendBtn`, all the `grades` will send to their `ContactNo`.

Code is for only 1 person

```
var com6 = new SerialPort(label7.Text);
if (!com6.IsOpen) com6.Open();
com6.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
com6.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
com6.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + ContactNo.Text + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
com6.WriteLine(textMessage.Text + (char)26 + Environment.NewLine);
com6.Close();
```

is it possible to stored it in array? like this one?

```
ArrayList Grades = new ArrayList();
ArrayList ContactNo = new ArrayList();
        Grades.Clear();
           ContactNo.Clear();


           con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblGrades where GradeLvl = '"+GLvl.Text+"', con);
            SqlDataReader rdr;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
            {

                ContactNo.Add(rdr["Phone Number"]);
                 Grades.Add(rdr["Grades"]);

            }
```

Or if you have other solution i will be grateful for it! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You possible use a Struct or custom Class for this.

**Sample**
Create class:

```
public MyClass {
private int _contactNO = {get; set;}
private int _grade = {get; set;}
private float _average = {get; set;}
private string _remarks = {get; set;}
}
```

and use it:

```
...
private Dictionary<int, MyClass> _myDicWithData = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();
...
_myDicWithData.Add(INT_KEY, MY_CLASS_OBJ);
```

and acces data by int key or edit it by your needs.